# Recyler view is not displaying anything

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, recyclerview-layout

I set a recycler view for displaying data from firestore. I almost did everything right.but when I run my app it is not showing any data. Someone please help me. I attached my code here. I added setLinearlayoutmanager and set visibility to visible for recyclerview. I tried to get a data from user and use that data to retrieve content from the database.

display_data.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
        tools:context=".displayData">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/deptName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter dept eg:IT"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
            tools:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/deptName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/deptName"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="Get" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

my java code display.java:

```
    public class displayData extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        RecyclerView mlist;
        EditText deptName;
        FirebaseFirestore db3;
        public List<Users> usersList;
        UsersListAdaptor usersListAdaptor;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);
            findViewById(R.id.getData).setOnClickListener(this);
            deptName=findViewById(R.id.deptName);
            mlist=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
            mlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mlist.setAdapter(usersListAdaptor);
            db3=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            usersList=new ArrayList<>();
            usersListAdaptor=new UsersListAdaptor(usersList);
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.getData:
                    getdata();
                    break;
            }
        }
    private void getdata() {
        String deptname=deptName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        CollectionReference cref=db3.collection("bookingdetails");
        Query q2=cref.whereEqualTo("dept",deptname);
        q2.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if(e!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                for(DocumentChange doc:queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                        Users users = doc.getDocument().toObject(Users.class);
                        usersList.add(users);
                        usersListAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

users.class

    package com.example.sarukesi.seminarbook;

    public class Users {
        String name;
        String dept;
        String time;
        String date;

        public Users() {
        }
        public Users(String name, String dept, String time, String date) {
            this.name = name;
            this.dept = dept;
            this.time = time;
            this.date = date;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDept() {
            return dept;
        }

        public void setDept(String dept) {
            this.dept = dept;
        }

        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }


    }
```

UsersListAdapter:

```
    public class UsersListAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersListAdaptor.ViewHolder> {

        List<Users> usersList;

        public UsersListAdaptor(List<Users> usersList) {
            this.usersList = usersList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,viewGroup,false);
            return  new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            viewHolder.tname.setText(usersList.get(i).getName());
            viewHolder.tdept.setText(usersList.get(i).getDept());
            viewHolder.ttime.setText(usersList.get(i).getTime());
            viewHolder.tdate.setText(usersList.get(i).getDate());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return usersList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            View mview;
            public TextView tname,tdept,ttime,tdate;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mview=itemView;
                tname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
                tdept=itemView.findViewById(R.id.depttxt);
                ttime=itemView.findViewById(R.id.timetxt);
                tdate=itemView.findViewById(R.id.datetxt);
            }
        }
    }
```

list_item.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nametxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/depttxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Dept"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timetxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datetxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What research have you done? RecyclerView is much discussed on the web and on SO. What have you tried to debug this? Also, try formatting your question so it is clear what is code and what is comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        mlist.setAdapter(usersListAdaptor);
        db3=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        usersList=new ArrayList<>();
        usersListAdaptor=new UsersListAdaptor(usersList);
```

You create a new adapter after assigning the old one. Move the first line to the end of this block

Comment: instead of snapshot listener i tried addonsuccess listener and instead of documentchange i used documentsnapshot.now it was working and thanks for helping me...